# What are the analogues in react hooks for the correct implementation of isLoading?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Then

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { userActions } from 'redux/actions/userActions';

class Example extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.userActions.get();
    }

    render() {
        let { data, isLoading } = this.props.users;

        if (isLoading) {
            return <div>loading</div>;
        }

        return <div>{data}</div>;
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ users }) => ({
    users,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    userActions: bindActionCreators(userActions, dispatch),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Example);
```

Now

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { userActions } from 'redux/actions/userActions';

export default function Example() {
    const users = useSelector(state => state.users);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    React.useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(userActions.get());
    }, [dispatch]);

    if (users.isLoading) {
        return <div>loading</div>;
    }

    return <div>{users.data}</div>;
}
```

With hooks, we get the default time from the reducer isLoading = false for the first time, and on components, we will first execute componentDidMount and set isLoading to true before rendering.

The question is how it is more elegant to resolve this case with react hooks?

Comment: But this example *does* uses react hooks, what kind of answer you expect?

Comment: @DennisVash, sorry, I mean redux-hooks, I fixed the tags

Comment: @DennisVash, and anyway I use react hook useEffect

Answer (score 0):

Your solution looks good. I do this kind of thing sometimes in my app. You just need to garantee that something will trigger the componenet re-render when your condition to re-render become true. In your case the loading condition depends on your redux state, so when this state change the component will automatically re-render correctly because of the useSelector hook. But if this was not the case, you could use a state, like this:

```
function MyComponent() {
    const [loaded, setLoaded] = React.useState(false);
    if (!loaded) {
        //Do something asynchronous and then use the setLoaded function to trigger the component re-render
        return <View>LOADING</View>;
    }
    return <View>DONE</View>;
}
```